# pass json path to response from background part of karate api automation

Tags: api, testing, karate, web-api-testing

I am working with karate api automation
I converted my response to json

```
 * json jsonres = response
```

I defined variable in background

```
* def responseJsonPath = ["ns1:initiateCreditDecisionResponse"]._["ns2:ApplicationResponse"]
```

after that I pass responseJsonPath to my response in test scenario part but it is not work

```
And def reasonCode = jsonres.responseJsonPath
```

I cannot print reasonCode

it should be mentioned that it works in following format

```
And def reasonCode = jsonres["ns1:initiateCreditDecisionResponse"]._["ns2:ApplicationResponse"]
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Java. Perhaps you meant Groovy tag instead?

Comment: yes it is karate api automation feature file

Comment: I see... But without knowing your full JSON response, it's hard to say what should be parsed

Comment: the problem is it is work properly in this form
jsonres["ns1:initiateCreditDecisionResponse"]._["ns2:ApplicationResponse"]
but when i try to define json path in background it is not working

Comment: no one can answer your question without an example. please create a simple sample of the response and then your steps which failed - so we can try run it locally. note that you can edit your question above, here itself. and if your response is big PLEASE don't dump it fully here, just create a simplified example so that we can understand